# How to call a function inside a function to work on a Tkinter button comand?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, button

I need help.
I'm developing a GUI where I have a function inside a function that I need to call in a tkinter button in order to make that button working, but I don´t how I can call the function that I need (func1).

Brief Code:

```
def func():
    def func1():
    func1()
func()

generatePDF = Button(fourthWindow, text="Gerar Relatório PDF", command=func1)
```

Comment: Usually, you do not need to nest function definitions.

Comment: In my case I really need.

Comment: Can you explain why ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler just to move func1 in the global namespace and call func1 inside func? Then func1 was easily accessible for your button.

Comment: The problem is func and func1 aren´t at the same scritp that tkinter is.

Comment: Please see my answer below and comment if there are any remaining issues. "Usually, you do not need to nest function definitions." **But, sometimes you do!** "Wouldn't it be much simpler just to move func1 in the global namespace and call func1 inside func?" **Maybe, maybe not. Plus, what approach would be more pythonic**.

Answer (score 0):

If func doesn't return anything, you can let func return func1 then implement func in the button

```
def func():
  def func1(): 
    # Statements 
  return func1() # func will return whatever func1 does
generatePDF = Button(fourthWindow, text="Gerar Relatório PDF", command=func) # the button will implement what func1 does
```

'''

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).